# Read File name and put it into Variable

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find a way to read a specific file name in a directory and then put the file name into a variable.  In my program I have a batch file that zips a folder called logs and then changes the name of zip to username_date_time.zip.

So basically if the filename was **jobs_03152015_1315.zip** I would want the entire file name but not the path stored into a variable.  The file starts off on the user's local machine.  It is then uploaded into a network share.

The network path will be uploaded to a database for others to view.  I want to just add the unique file name to the end of a pre set path.  Here is the code I am using.

```
Dim filePath As String = "c:\temp\logs\"

If (System.IO.Directory.Exists(filePath)) Then

    For Each file As String In filePath
        If file.Contains(".zip") Then
            Dim zip As String = file
            testbox.Text = zip
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: You can use the `FileInfo` class in the `System.IO` namespace to get the filename. Since you are using the Directories, iterate over the directory with `FileInfo`, and if the `FileInfo.Extension` is equal to ".zip", then store the `FileInfo.Name` into a variable. More info on the MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
Dim FilePath As String = "c:\temp\logs\"
    If (System.IO.Directory.Exists(FilePath)) Then
        For Each File As String In System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(FilePath)
            If File.Contains(".zip") Then
                Dim info As New System.IO.FileInfo(File)
                zip = info.Name
                testbox.Text = zip
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks but i adapted your code to the easiest implementation for you. This is NOT the best optimization.

Comment: That's ok this is for a very small app that I am using for work.  There is only one zip file in the directory and it is created at the end of the application then deleted.  I would imagine anything else beyond that would need to more robust, but I just started learning VB.NET for work three months ago.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Keep on! People underated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate all files using the `GetFiles()` method of the static (shared in VB) `Directory` class, see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx).

Assuming you have more then 1 file I add the files to a listbox control. But you could change that if you wish. I get the filename using the [`Path` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx). You will find a lot other helpful functions in this class.

```
 Dim searchPath = "C:\temp\logs"

 Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.zip")

 For Each file In files
     listbox1.Items.Add(path.GetFileName(file))
 Next
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop doesn't read anything. The string variable `filePath` is just the name of the directory, not a list of the files in that directory.  Calling For Each over a string simply enumerates each character contained in the string

To get a list of files contained in that folder you need `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` and pass the filePath variable and the extension required.

It seems that you are interested only to find if that folder contains at least one file with zip extension. If this is the case then you could remove the explicit loop and write simply

```
 Dim file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath, "*.zip").FirstOrDefault()
 If file IsNot Nothing Then
    testbox.Text = Path.GetFileName(file)
 End If
```

Using `Path.GetFileName` will return just the file without the path part